# How to parse complex JSON file format using pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I want to parse the following file: ([link for the complete following json file](https://github.com/statsbomb/open-data/blob/master/data/lineups/7581.json))

```
[ {
  "team_id" : 776,
  "team_name" : "Denmark",
  "lineup" : [ {
    "player_id" : 3027,
    "player_name" : "Mathias Jattah-Njie Jørgensen",
    "player_nickname" : "Zanka",
    "jersey_number" : 13,
    "country" : {
      "id" : 61,
      "name" : "Denmark"
    }
  }, {
    "player_id" : 3043,
    "player_name" : "Christian Dannemann Eriksen",
    "player_nickname" : "Christian Eriksen",
    "jersey_number" : 10,
    "country" : {
      "id" : 61,
      "name" : "Denmark"
    }
  }, {
    "player_id" : 3815,
    "player_name" : "Kasper Schmeichel",
    "player_nickname" : null,
    "jersey_number" : 1,
    "country" : {
      "id" : 61,
      "name" : "Denmark"
    }
  },  {
    "player_id" : 6356,
    "player_name" : "Michael Krohn-Dehli",
    "player_nickname" : null,
    "jersey_number" : 2,
    "country" : {
      "id" : 61,
      "name" : "Denmark"
    }
  } ]
}, {
  "team_id" : 785,
  "team_name" : "Croatia",
  "lineup" : [ {
    "player_id" : 3444,
    "player_name" : "Danijel Subašić",
    "player_nickname" : null,
    "jersey_number" : 23,
    "country" : {
      "id" : 56,
      "name" : "Croatia"
    }
}, {
    "player_id" : 6308,
    "player_name" : "Josip Pivarić",
    "player_nickname" : null,
    "jersey_number" : 22,
    "country" : {
      "id" : 56,
      "name" : "Croatia"
    }
  } ]
} ]
```

Basically, what i want from these kind of json file is to parse the lineup from every country.
My code:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Catalin\Desktop\World Cup Data\data\lineups\7581.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:    # r inainte de string ca sa il ia ca raw data
    data = json.load(data_file)
df = pd.json_normalize(data, sep = "_")
export_csv = df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\Catalin\Desktop\TestLineup7581.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

I'm exporting the dataframe into csv format because i want to see how the json was parsed and it looks like this:
[image]

So, my question is, what other function like json_normalize() can I use? If exists.

Comment: You're not asking us to improve your code, you're asking us to write it for you, and that's not what is expected on StackOverflow. You are expected to code your own attempt at solving your problem, post the code here, and then ask some specific question about it. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details.

Comment: well no, where did i asked for code? a simple suggestion is enough (later edit: how i'm supposed to solve my own problem if i don't know how? if i had any idea i wouldn't ask for help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.json_normalize(data, 'lineup')` should do what you want. If you want `team_id` and `team_name`, put `pd.json_normalize(data, 'lineup', ['team_id', 'team_name'])`.

Check the [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) documentation examples for more info.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what i was lookign for

Comment: If you could mark it as the correct answer that would be great!